# Moving Dropdown DataFieldCategory to bottom of list

Tags: c#, list, linq, drop-down-menu

I have a list of "Care Items" that possess a soft delete bool, an ID, a name, and a Category.

Currently, I am querying for all! IsDeleted and it populates just fine under with each item grouped under their appropriate categories.

I am now changing it so that items that are IsDeleted populate in a "Disabled Care Item" Category. That works fine, but "Disabled Care Item" is showing up where you would expect it to in the middle of a list with 10-20 categories each with at least a few items in each. So disabled gets lost. I would love to be able to move the disabled category and items to the bottom of the list, but each time I try I am getting implicit casting errors between my lists or errors against IQueryable since I'm LINQing for these results.

I know there is somebody clever out there who has a solution for this complete noob.

```
var query =  CareItemFactory.Instance.GetByCareProgram(facilityId, careProgramId);

if (!includeDisabled)
{
    query = query.Where(x => !x.IsDisabled && !x.CareItemCategory.IsDisabled);
}

return query.Select(i => new CareItemView
{
    ID = i.ID,
    Category = i.IsDisabled == true ? $"Disabled Care Items" : i.CareItemCategory.Name,
    Name = i.Name
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var query =  CareItemFactory.Instance.GetByCareProgram(facilityId, careProgramId);

var resultQuery = query.Where(x => !x.IsDisabled && !x.CareItemCategory.IsDisabled)
    .Select(i => new CareItemView
    {
        ID = i.ID,
        Category = i.CareItemCategory.Name,
        Name = i.Name
    });

if (includeDisabled)
{
    var resultQuery = resultQuery.Union(query.Where(x => x.IsDisabled || x.CareItemCategory.IsDisabled)
    .Select(i => new CareItemView
    {
        ID = i.ID,
        Category = $"Disabled Care Items",
        Name = i.Name
    }));
}

return resultQuery.ToList();
```